# How to replace after pasting automatically in microsoft word

Tags: ms-word

I have created a new style in Microsoft word and this makes my life easier to format the pasted content . I want to make my life a bit more easier . I want to also run replace facility for removing paragraph mark with a space in my pasted content . Is it possible to automatically replace while applying our custom style to pasted paragraphs in Microsoft word ?

Thank you .

Comment: Yes, if you write the code to do both tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Can you please tell me in a more elaborate way ? I welcome your reply .

Comment: You could start by recording a macro. SO is not a code writing service. Please take time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just record a macro of applying the style and doing the Replace.

Comment: Thanks a lot . You are the one Timothy .